# where Model from two table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this two tables 'posts' and 'category'
and i want to apply this route.

and make a model query to verify that the post exists in the required category.

note i have applied belongsTo relation to posts model.

Comment: You can perform a simple check in your controller method: `if ($post->category == $category) { // return view }`

Comment: not clear enough so what do you want to do?

Comment: i want a model query 

like

$post = Post:where('slug',$post)->first();

and i want to verify category too

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the Collections [contains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-contains) method:

```
if ($category->posts->contains($postId)) //do something
```

Comment: i want to verify both parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify it via the db, you can use the following statement

```
$post = Post:where('slug','=',$post)->whereHas('category',function($query){
        $query->where('slug','=',$category);
})->first();
```

You must have a category relationship set up in the post model to use the above statement.